# Item in column with overlay in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays, multicolumn

I try to make this work, but any try with `column` or various other thing produce the same error message.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \item $(-3)+(+15)=12$
        \item $(-25)+(+5)=-20$
    \end{multicols}

    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the use of `multicolumn` a requirement? The following, using the standard columns environment generates overlays with the items arranged in columns.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item $(-3)+(+15)=12$
        \item $(-4)+(+15)=11$
\end{itemize}       
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} 
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
         \item $(-25)+(+5)=-20$
         \item $(-35)+(+15)=-20$
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I notice that you put `itemize` inside `columns`, I try the to put `itemize` inside `multicols` and it works. I didn't think to try that !!